# Relation extraction via chunking using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, named-entity-recognition, chunking

I am trying to figure out how to use NLTK's cascading chunker as per [Chapter 7 of the NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html). Unfortunately, I'm running into a few issues when performing non-trivial chunking measures.

Let's start with this phrase:

`"adventure movies between 2000 and 2015 featuring performances by daniel craig"`

I am able to find all the relevant NPs when I use the following grammar:

`grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN.*>+}"`

However, I am not sure how to build nested structures with NLTK. The book gives the following format, but there are clearly a few things missing (e.g. How does one actually specify multiple rules?):

```
grammar = r"""
  NP: {<DT|JJ|NN.*>+}          # Chunk sequences of DT, JJ, NN
  PP: {<IN><NP>}               # Chunk prepositions followed by NP
  VP: {<VB.*><NP|PP|CLAUSE>+$} # Chunk verbs and their arguments
  CLAUSE: {<NP><VP>}           # Chunk NP, VP
  """
```

In my case, I'd like to do something like the following:

```
grammar = r"""
          MEDIA: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN.*>+}
          RELATION: {<V.*>}{<DT>?<JJ>*<NN.*>+}
          ENTITY: {<NN.*>}
          """
```

Assuming that I'd like to use a cascaded chunker for my task, what syntax would I need to use? Additionally, is it possible for me to specify specific words (e.g. "directed" or "acted") when using a chunker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment on the relationship extraction part, not least because you don't give any details on what you want to do and what kind of data you have. So this is a rather partial answer.

> a.) How does cascading chunking work in NLTK b.) Is it possible to treat the chunker like a context-free grammar, and if so, how?

As I understand section  ["Building nested structure with cascaded chunkers"](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#building-nested-structure-with-cascaded-chunkers) in the NLTK book, you can use it with a context free grammar but you have to apply it repeatedly to get the recursive structure. Chunkers are flat, but you can add chunks on top of chunks.

> c.) How can I use chunking to perform relation extraction?

I can't really speak to that, and anyway as I said you don't give any specifics; but if you're dealing with real text, my understanding is is that hand-written rulesets for *any* task are useless unless you have a large team and a lot of time. Look into the probabilistic tools that come with the NLTK. It'll be a whole lot easier if you have an annotated training corpus.

Anyway, a couple more comments about the RegexpParser.

1. You'll find a lot more use examples on http://www.nltk.org/howto/chunk.html. (Unfortunately it's not a real how-to, but a test suite.)
2. According to [this,](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~trnka/CISC889-11S/lectures/dongqing-chunking.pdf) you can specify multiple expansion rules like this:

   ```
   patterns = """NP: {<DT|PP\$>?<JJ>*<NN>}
       {<NNP>+}
       {<NN>+}
   """
   ```

   I should add that grammars can have multiple rules with the same left side. That should add some flexibility with grouping related rules, etc.